# creating methods in an abstract class

Tags: java, class, methods, abstract

So what I have here is an abstract class in Java.  I need to make setter and getter functions for setupCostBase and monthlyCostBase so they can take in values from the other subclasses in the project. However, whenever I try to make the setter, I always get an error reading "< identifier > expected".

Not quite sure how to fix this.

```
abstract public class Carrier {

    private String name = "Unknown Carrier";
    private double setupCostBase = 0.00;
    private double monthlyCostBase = 0.00;

    public Carrier(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

    private void setSetupCost(setupCostBase){
        this.setupCostBase = setupCostBase;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really poor title for your question. The title suggests it's about methods, but really you just have a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

`"<identifier> expected"` is a kind of generic error which suggests that your syntax is incorrect.

In this case, you have not declared the type of the parameter `setupCostBase` in this method:

```
private void setSetupCost(setupCostBase){
```

It should be a double:

```
private void setSetupCost(double setupCostBase){
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `setSetupCost()` does not have a type for for `setupCostBase`.
Try this:

```
private void setSetupCost(double setupCostBase){
    this.setupCostBase = setupCostBase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your setters should be visible from the outside so they should not be private. Also in your example you forgot type of the method parameter. Your setters should look as follows:

```
public void setSetupCostBase(double setupCostBase) {
    this.setupCostBase = setupCostBase;
}

public void setMonthlyCostBase(double monthlyCostBase) {
    this.monthlyCostBase = monthlyCostBase;
}
```